# Excel 2011 Mac VBA Combobox value

Tags: excel, vba, macos, combobox

In excel 2011 on the mac, I have a spread sheet with two controls. A combobox and a button. the combo box is named Crops and i want to access the value of that box when clicking the button.

The obvious Crops.Value that would work in windows office does not seem to work and i get an error saying the Crops object is missing.

Is this (simple) task possible with VBA on the Mac?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ok solved it.  Active X objects do not work on the mac.  You have to use Forms elements and then if you want to access the value of a dropdown this is the VBA code.  Hope it helps someone else.

assuming Crops was the combobox, Itm will have the value.

```
With ActiveSheet.DropDowns("Crops")
    Itm = .list(.ListIndex)
End With
```

Comment: Great to hear it is sorted. You can accept your own answer by clicking the hollow checkmark next to the up/down arrows on this answer.